# How to remove a string from the filename recursively

Tags: bash

Read the name of the folder and look for it in the file name and delete it from it, example:

--
\John Carter
marsCarter - John Carter.pdf

\Sylvia Alter
Sylvia Alter - Corre y no pares.mobi

\Other Name
Other Name - see the diabolic.epub

And it should look like this:

--
\John Carter
marsCarter.pdf

```
\Sylvia Alter\
        Corre y no pares.mobi

\Other Name\
        see the diabolis.epub
```

Could you give me an idea of ​​how to get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename(1)` and `dirname(1)` to get file name and folder name.

```
> basename "./John Carter/marsCarter - John Carter.pdf"
> marsCarter - John Carter.pdf

> basename "$(dirname "./John Carter/marsCarter - John Carter.pdf")"
> John Carter
```

Having that, you can try to use `sed(1)` to remove folder name from the file name.

```
> echo "marsCarter - John Carter.pdf" | sed -r 's/ - John Carter//'
> marsCarter.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had contemplated something like that but I messed around a bit to make it recursive with more folders within the same directory. Thank you